# Installation issues from the beginning

Tags: system-installation

First to start out, I'm very new to Linux, I can get around a little, but beyond that, I rely on forums and posts to get what I need done. Having said that, I've been attempting to install Linux in some form on my older PC for a week now to no avail. I got Debian stable on there and running, but it was hit or miss with the loading, and then I found I couldn't do what I wanted with it, so I moved to Ubuntu Server, didn't work, got frustrated and am now trying Ubuntu desktop. I've gotten errors from the 'HD0' to need to load kernal first, to nothing but blank screens. I've attempted multiple reinstalls, and have tried boot-repair. I don't know what I am doing and why this won't work.

This is the pastebin from the boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23297489/

This is attempting to install only Ubuntu on the HDD, no other OS.

System info:

CPU: AMD Phenom II x4 995 3.2 GHz

16gb RAM

80GB SDD

CDROM

Unsure of Legacy/UEFI modes, my CMOS setup does not allow me to change that.

Let me know if you guys need anymore info, or wish to help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add hardware (RAM, CPU, HDD space, etc.), whether your system is Legacy/CSM/UEFI, and whether you are dual-booting.

Comment: AMD Phenom II x4 955 3.2 ghz CPU
16gb RAM
And I'm currently just trying to install everything on a 80gb SSD, also have 1 cdrom drive in as well.
Clean install. 
My system doesn't allow me to change from Legacy/CSM/UEFI so it's a default I suppose.

Comment: Are you wiping or dual-booting? Is your system Legacy, CSM, UEFI, or a combination? I can't help you if you won't fully answer my question.

Comment: I edited my comment above, was attempting to add clean breaks in it, guess it didn't matter...

Comment: There are no line breaks in comments. You should really be [edit]ing this into your question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely an install in legacy-mode and checking the boot-info-summary the install looks clean.
The problem seems to be with your graphics-card `Radeon HD 5770`.
To boot to Ubuntu do the following:

1. Immediately after the BIOS splash screen during boot, press and hold   the SHIFT button. This will display you grub containing a list of kernels and recovery option
2. Select the first kernel and press<kbd>e</kbd> to edit boot options
3. Find the line ending with quiet splash. Add the `nomode`- option before these key words - i.e. so the line looks like `[...]nomodeset quiet splash`
4. Press CTRL + X to boot

Look for detailed information for this steps [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu).

Open the dash and type "drivers", click on the `Additional Drivers`-icon and check if Ubuntu give you any options to install an
appropriate driver for the graphics card. See detailed information for this step [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers).

A driver for your graphics card is available, but it seems to use it you will have to use Ubuntu 14.04. Look for detailed information and how to install this driver [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous/detail?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064&rev=15.9).

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I ended up getting a clean install after numerous attempts at just reinstalling over and over again.

Comment: Thanks again for actually looking at the paste boot info.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just reinstalling over and over again, and eventually got it to load in and was able to see everything and perform updates. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Glad you were able to get things working